# ASP.net content tags, and the id attribute

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've made a few master pages in visual studio, and then a few implementing pages, and Visual Studio sticks ID attributes onto all of my  tags:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="OtherContent" ></asp:Content>
```

What gives with the IDs?  What are they good for? How do I access them from the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controls that run on the server must have an ID attribute as a unique identifier. They are good for finding child controls and keeping the control hierarchy in place. If you have a TextBox that sits in a Panel that sits in an UpdatePanel that's in a WebUserControl that's in a ContentPlaceHolder that's in a Page, then all it takes is one of them not to have a proper ID attribute in order keep the connection between TextBox and Page.

In order to access it from the code behind you need to have the `runat="server"` attribute set on this tag.

Comment: I'm curious about the asp:Content tag specifically.  So far any way I try and use FindControl, to access this tag, I can't.  I can however find everything I put on the page, runat="server"